# Change of "Site Settings > Clipboard" after latest update of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, updates

I updated Chrome to version 107. On lot of websites I use JavaScript functions like navigator.clipboard.readText() which copy text to clipboard.

Before update any website need confirmation. Now I have to confirm it on every website.

I am not sure if there was (before update) option in settings "Site Settings > Clipboard" to allow it and don't ask on all websites or if there was anything in chrome:flags to do it.

But I need to allow it without confirmation on all websites like before update.

Please how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Try clearing the list of websites. Deny/Allow lists work strange when one exists but the other doesn’t especially when it comes to allow lists

Comment: I cleared the list but it doesn't help. There are still the same 2 options. There is option "Sites can ask to see text and images on your clipboard" but I need option "Sites can see text and images on your clipboard" (= allow it for all websites I will browse without asking)